# C# how to get orignal screen bounds after zooming

Tags: c#, screen, screen-orientation

When I zoom in from window setting it is never capturing exact desktop screen. it just zoom the Bitmap Picture and show us .

[image]

how can I get the the original picture after zoomin Window. 
**Here is Code:-**

```
 private static BitmapSource CopyScreen()
    {
        BitmapSource BS = null;
        int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
        int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
        int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
        int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
        using (Bitmap screenBmp = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
            {
                bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, screenBmp.Size);

                BS = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(screenBmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            }
        }


        return BS;
    }
```

from Above code I get zoomed pic. 
[image]

**What I want:- that is the original displayed pic not zoomed pic (just the display showing on my desktop as it is)**
 
 [image]

I want to capture screen of desktop but the bounds of screen not getting correct while zoom in Window. Is it possible to capture a screenshot of its actual resolution instead of zoom in .It captures the screen of upper right Corner

Comment: what should I use it instead of it then ?

Comment: never mind, not even sure it's that by looking more at it. sorry.

Comment: Just a remark on [SystemInformation.VirtualScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) - "This property is supported only on Windows 98, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and the Windows Server 2003 family." - and you are showing Windows 10 prints, so...

Comment: Other methods also doing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the sizing options in CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap.

However, if you only need to make screenshots, you don't need it, as you can use the Bitmap as is:

```
Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width,
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

using (Graphics screenGraph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
{
    screenGraph.CopyFromScreen(
        SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
        SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
        0,
        0,
        SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size,
        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
screenshot.Save("screenshot.png");
```

If you really need a bitmapsource, you can use a MemoryStream with whatever format you want.

Comment: I need Bitmap Source because I don't want to save it I just show it in `Image` in Wpf